# How do I display fetch response in react

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I want to display the response from my fetch request in react. So far, I built the fetch request and set up the useEffect and useState hooks. The response is an object. What am I doing wrong?

```
function App() {

const url = 'https://api.gemini.com/v1/book/btcusd'

const [orders, setOrders] = useState([])

const fetchData = () => {
  fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    setOrders(data)
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
}
  
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
}, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{orders.asks}</h1>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If `orders` is meant to be an object, why initialise it as an array?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at that API, the `asks` property holds an array of objects. You would need to map those to JSX elements in order to display them.

Also, if `orders` is meant to be an object, you should not initialise it as an array.

Finally, you should always check the [Response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property to see if the request resolved successfully.

```js
// fetch-data.js
const url = "https://api.gemini.com/v1/book/btcusd";

export const fetchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw Object.assign(new Error(`${res.status}: ${res.statusText}`), {
      url,
      text: await res.text(),
    });
  }
  return res.json();
};
```

```jsx
// App.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { fetchData } from "./fetch-data";

function App() {
  // init with an object with empty `asks` array
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState({ asks: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(setOrders).catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">

      {/* Map over the data */}
      {orders.asks.map(({ price, amount }, i) => (
        <dl key={i}>
          <dt>Price</dt>
          <dd>{price}</dd>

          <dt>Amount</dt>
          <dd>{amount}</dd>
        </dl>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is an object. You should use `map` to loop.

```
const url = "https://api.gemini.com/v1/book/btcusd";

  const [orders, setOrders] = useState({ asks: [{price: 0, amount: 0}], bids: [{price: 0, amount: 0}] });

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data); //Data: {bids: Array(50), asks: Array(50)}
        setOrders(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <th>Ask price</th>
          <th>Ask amount</th>
          <th>Bid price</th>
          <th>Bid amount</th>
        </thead>
      {orders.asks?.map((e, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            <tr>
              <td>{e.price}</td>
              <td>{e.amount}</td>
              <td>{orders.bids[i].price}</td>
              <td>{orders.bids[i].amount}</td>
            </tr>
          </>
        )
      })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

[image]

Comment: How would I display both bids and asks together

Comment: How do you want to show both bids and asks ? please example.

Comment: I have the asks in a html table right now, I'd like to also display the bids in the table. I've tried doing the same thing but switching out asks for bids but it doesn't work.

Comment: i have updated my answer. You can try it.

Answer (score -2):

You Can use map function to display each item

eg:

```
orders.asks.map(item=>
<div>
  <h1>{item.price}</h1>
  <h1>{item.amount}</h1>
</div>
)
```

Comment: Always add a key when you are mapping